# When does a pointer variable has its address changed?

Tags: pointers, go

Consider [the following example](https://play.golang.org/p/O4FoM7sxucx) and notice how the location of pointer variable `a` remains fixed, as expected:

```
var a *int

v1 := 1
v2 := 2

a = &v1
fmt.Printf("%p\n", &a) // output: 0x1040c128
a = &v2
fmt.Printf("%p\n", &a) // output: 0x1040c128
```

Now consider the following struct definition:

```
type foo struct {
    bar int
}
```

If `a` is declared as a pointer variable to `foo` as in [this example](https://play.golang.org/p/tqH2nsVsTpS), its location in memory does *not* remain fixed.

```
var a *foo

v1 := foo{bar: 1}
v2 := foo{bar: 2}

a = &v1
fmt.Printf("%p\n", a) // output: 0x10414020
a = &v2
fmt.Printf("%p\n", a) // output: 0x10414024
```

Why is that?

Comment: Modify the second example to print &a and you will see that address of a does not change.

Comment: You are quite right. Missed this, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you just didn't make a typo and used `fmt.Printf("%p\n", a)` instead of `fmt.Printf("%p\n", &a)` because the first one uses `&a` and your second example uses `a`.

**Long answer:**

With

```
fmt.Printf("%p\n", a)
```

you're printing out the value of `a` which is of type `*foo` which is a pointer. Roughly speaking a pointer is a variable holding an address of a memory location. With

```
 a = &v1
```

you set `a` to the address of `v1`

```
 a = &v2
```

you set `a` to the address of `v2`. `v1` and `v2` have different locations in memory and thus you when you print the value of a you'll see exactly that.

If you use

```
var a *foo

v1 := foo{bar: 1}
v2 := foo{bar: 2}

a = &v1
fmt.Printf("%p\n", &a)
a = &v2
fmt.Printf("%p\n", &a)
```

then you'll see the same number printed twice because now you're printing out the location of a. So:

```
a = &v
fmt.Printf("%p\n", a) // prints location of v, not location of a

a = &v
fmt.Printf("%p\n", &a) // prints location of a, not location of v
```

Remark:

There's some ambiguity as to what people call a pointer and what an address. Some say that a pointer is an address because it contains an "address of a memory location" but a pointer is not *actually* a memory address depending on the exact context. Also, `a` points to `b` usually means that `a` is a pointer containing the address of `b`. Likewise, `&v` is either referred to as "the address of v" and "a pointer to v" which (at least in my opinion) are equally correct which is why I originally used "set a to a pointer to v".

Comment: Please consider fixing the wording a bit: you're too frivolous with mixing "pointer" and "address" terms, which are not the same. A pointer `*T` is a data type which contains the address of a memory location which holds a value of type `T`. Hence one does not "set `a` to a pointer to `v1`", instead one sets `a` to the address of `v1`. Also, "a pointer is just a memory location" is nonsense: any variable is "just a memory location", but this is of little help to understand the matters here…

Comment: …saying instead "a pointer is a variable holding an address of a memory location" would be way more clear.

Comment: yep, agreed. will fix.

Comment: @kostix there's some ambuigity there though. The expression `&v1` conceptually does return a pointer to `v1` thus `a := &v1` sets `a` to a pointer to `v1` (or assigns if you prefer assign over set). I don't think this is wrong... it's just using different terms to mean the same thing.

Comment: Agreed. Still, I like the updated version more—the flow of reasoning is now crystal-clear IMO; upvoted.